# Unable to mount a second hard drive in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk, ext4

I am adding a second drive to my Ubuntu Server. It was previously in a FreeNas system, but I got rid of the XFS partition and created an ext4 partition (in an older Ubuntu system). I then backed up all my data onto it, then installed the disk in my Ubuntu Server.

dmesg | tail

```
[  294.570830] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  365.523173] exe (1269): /proc/1269/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1269/oom_score_adj instead.
[  516.249248] EXT4-fs (sdb): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  518.965799] EXT3-fs (sdb): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdb.
```

I also have a testdisk.log file as follows

```
Thu Jul 28 19:40:00 2011
Command line: TestDisk

TestDisk 6.11, Data Recovery Utility, April 2009
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 2.6.38-8-server (#42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011)
Compiler: GCC 4.5 - Oct 17 2010 19:13:58
ext2fs lib: 1.41.14, ntfs lib: 10:0:0, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none
/dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sda: size       3907029168 sectors
/dev/sda: user_max   3907029168 sectors
/dev/sda: native_max 18446744073321613488 sectors
/dev/sda: dco        18446744073321613488 sectors
/dev/sdb: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sdb: size       3907029168 sectors
/dev/sdb: user_max   3907029168 sectors
/dev/sdb: native_max 18446744073321613488 sectors
/dev/sdb: dco        18446744073321613488 sectors
Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - CHS 1 1 1, sector size=512
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63, sector size=512 - ATA ST32000542AS
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63, sector size=512 - ATA ST32000542AS

Partition table type (auto): EFI GPT
/dev/sdb: Host Protected Area (HPA) present.
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - ATA ST32000542AS
Partition table type: EFI GPT

Analyse Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
hdr_size=92
hdr_lba_self=1
hdr_lba_alt=3907029167 (expected 3907029167)
hdr_lba_start=34
hdr_lba_end=3907029134
hdr_lba_table=2
hdr_entries=128
hdr_entsz=128
Current partition structure:
 1 P FreeBSD Swap                 128    4194431    4194304 [swap-ada0]
 2 P Unknown                  4194432 3907029134 3902834703 [ada0]

search_part()
Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/14888, s_mnt_count=5/25, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 487854337
recover_EXT2: part_size 3902834696
     MS Data                  4194432 3907029127 3902834696 [D1]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock, 1998 GB / 1861 GiB

Results
   P MS Data                  4194432 3907029127 3902834696 [D1]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock, 1998 GB / 1861 GiB

interface_write()
 1 P MS Data                  4194432 3907029127 3902834696 [D1]
write!
No extended partition
You will have to reboot for the change to take effect.

TestDisk exited normally.
```

I don't mean to just dump log files and ask someone else to "make it work" but I find that in this case the testdisk.log would provide better incite than my explanation.

I would really like to be able to use this drive without having to reformat it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an [EFI GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table there. You'll need support for that in your kernel. As a quick-check, do `zgrep CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION /proc/config.gz`. [Here is a HOWTO](http://www.pjc.me.uk/efi-gpt/index.html) on mounting partitions of such a disk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up installing Ubuntu Desktop because I was having problems with audio drivers. Interestingly the hard drive mounted without problem in Ubuntu Desktop.